# Best lightweight web server (only static content) for windows

Tags: windows, iis-6, static-content

I got application server running in Windows – IIS6.0 with Zend Server to execute PHP. I am looking for lightweight static content only web server on this same machine which will relive IIS form handling static content and increase performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx is available on Windows if you want to serve things from that. Unfortunately the 'Windows web-server' space is very dominated by IIS, followed by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

use light weight httpd for windows. it has a very good reputation on linux. find it here: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lhttpd/)